# Execute function once earlier process is completed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

live.js

```
const [report, setReport] = useState([]);
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  pose.onResults(onResults);  => pose runs every second which runs onResults function every second
}, []);

const onResults = async () => {
  setResult(results.poseLandmarks); ==> It set above state name result
};

useEffect(() => {
   updateReport(); ==> as result state update this runs function updateReport
}, [result]);



const updateReport = async (result) => {
  let reportData = [...report];
  let updatedReport = [];
  let saveReport = [];
  if (report.length > 99) {
    saveReport = reportData.slice(0, 100);
    let body = {
     room_id: roomId,
     formatReport: {
      "frames": saveReport
     },
     session: sessionId
   };
   reportData.splice(0, 100);
   await awsUpload(body.formatReport, body.room_id); ==> This function uploads file to aws
}
reportData.push(updatedReport);
setReport(reportData); ===> It set in report state
```

}

onResult is running at each second I want once updateReport function runs it must complete all its execution before running again but before completing execution it runs again as result state which is dependency is updating at each second

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a flag to track wether `updateReport` is currently already running:

```
const [isUpdatingReport, setIsUpdatingReport] = useState(false);
```

And then in `onResult` only call `updateReport` if it's not currently running:

```
const onResults = async () => {
  setResult(results.poseLandmarks);
  if (!isUpdatingReport) {
    setIsUpdatingReport(true);
    updateReport();
  }
};
```

In addition, at the end of all the async stuff in `updateReport`, make sure to signal that the work is done with

```
const updateReport = async (result) => {
  // ...
  setIsUpdatingReport(false);
};
```

This way there will only be one report being updated at the same time.

Some other thoughts on your code:

- `updateReport` has one argument (`result`) in your snippet but gets called without arguments. Maybe something missing?
- Do you really need `result` to be a state variable? It seems that its only purpose is to be processed by `updateReport`. If that is true you could simply pass it to the function. But maybe it gets rendered in the component, don't know.

Comment: when it does not match isUpdatingReport condition it will not go in if and exit the function which will again call onResults function hence data will be lost as results value gets updated rather it must wait till update report is completed

Comment: Oh ok, you mean you need to process *all* results, every time the 1-second interval happens? That means you need to put them in a queue and process them first-in-first-out.

Comment: Yes need to do like that